# Adding dictionary to array throws typeerror _a is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

My first Angular app in Angular 5.

I'm trying to create a data source for my material table. Here's the code that creates the data source:

```
  getDrinksDataSource(): MatTableDataSource<{}> {
    const drinkList = [];

    for (let entry of this.settingsService.drinks) {
      console.log('Adding:' + entry);
      const drinkEntry = {drink: entry};
      drinkList.push(drinkEntry); //<-Line 24, not 60 characters long.
    }

    const dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    dataSource.data = drinkList;
    return dataSource;
  }
```

this.settingsService.drinks returns an array of simple strings, which is confirmed by the console.log that displays the strings.

The problem is that I get the following error in my console:

```
TypeError: _a is undefined
Stack trace:
DrinksComponent.prototype.getDrinksDataSource@webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/drinks/drinks.component.ts:24:60
View_DrinksComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/DrinksComponent.ngfactory.js:66:21
debugUpdateDirectives@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14855:12
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14002:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14353:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14285:13
```

This is, of course, in the component called from my html template.

Here's my html template:

```
<h3>Drinks</h3>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="getDrinksDataSource()" matSort>

  <!-- Drinks Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="drinks">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Drinks </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.drink}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Row definition -->
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

I have highlighted line 24 in my code. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint in Chrome debugger just before that line. Nothing looks out of ordinary. Assuming you are using Angular-CLI and assuming that the compilation is successful.

Comment: please show your html code as well.

Comment: @Chybie Done. Thanks for your interest.